# How can I unpin MSI Center in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, pinning

MSI Center is pinned in my Windows 10. I can't unpin it. How can I unpin MSI Center in Windows 10?

---

What I tried:

Closing doesn't help:

[image]

Editing `C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\LayoutModification.xml` to remove all mentions of "MSI Center" and restarting Windows doesn't help.

Removing `C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\LayoutModification.xml` and restarting Windows doesn't help.

Using this [Batch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file) script from [thewindowsclub.com](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/unpin-all-taskbar-icons-at-once-in-windows) to remove all pinned applications doesn't help:

```
DEL /F /S /Q /A "%AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar\*"
REG DELETE HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Taskband /F
taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe & start explorer
```

Note that `C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\DefaultLayouts.xml` has no mentions of "MSI Center".

Answer (score 4):

Go to `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\LayoutModification.xml` and remove the line:

```
<taskbar:UWA AppUserModelID="9426MICRO-STARINTERNATION.MSICenter_kzh8wxbdkxb8p!App" />
```

Then restart Windows.

Comment: I also had to remove the same from this file: `C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\LayoutModification.xml`.